# Not understanding why JavaScript Reduce not returning an object with length of 3

Tags: javascript

I've got a simple example with reduce and it returns a length of two and not three.  Why? I would have expected it will iterate through all three.

```js
    const sessions = [{
        "id": 101,
        "sessionId": 6182,
        "attendvalue": 2
    },
        {
            "id": 102,
            "sessionId": 6183,
            "attendvalue": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "sessionId": 6184,
            "attendvalue": 1
        }
    ];
    
    const sessionsObj = sessions.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur.sessionId] = cur;
        return acc;
    });
    console.log(sessionsObj.length);
```

Comment: Cause you are missing the initial value `reduce(acc, {})`, do `console.log(sessions)` to see whats going on

Comment: Initial value! [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to pass the initial value:**

> **initialValue** | `Optional`
>
> Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. **`If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used`**. Calling [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

*Actually the result will be an object with further properties.*

```js
const sessions = [{    "id": 101,    "sessionId": 6182,    "attendvalue": 2  },  {    "id": 102,    "sessionId": 6183,    "attendvalue": 0  },  {    "id": 103,    "sessionId": 6184,    "attendvalue": 1  }];

const sessionsObj = sessions.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.sessionId] = cur;
  return acc;
}, { });
//  ^
//  |
//  +---- Initial value

console.log(Object.values(sessionsObj).length);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is length not valid? If not why?

Comment: @Pete key-value pair objects don't have the property `length`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set the starting object, the second parameter in reduce.

Also, you'll need to use `Object.keys` to count the number of items.

Try it like this:

```js
const sessions = [{
    "id": 101,
    "sessionId": 6182,
    "attendvalue": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "sessionId": 6183,
    "attendvalue": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 103,
    "sessionId": 6184,
    "attendvalue": 1
  }
];

const sessionsObj = sessions.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.sessionId] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.keys(sessionsObj).length);
```